# Dataframe check if 2 columns contain same elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set

I have a data frame and with 2 columns X & Y.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'X': ['a', 'a,b,c', 'a,d', 'e,f', 'a,c,d,f', 'e'], 
'Y': ['a', 'a,c,b', 'd,a', 'e,g', 'a,d,f,g', 'e']
})
```

I want to create a new column('Match') in the dataframe such if the columns X & Y have the same elements, then True else False.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'X': ['a', 'a,b,c', 'a,d', 'e,f', 'a,c,d,f', 'e'], 
'Y': ['a', 'a,c,b', 'd,a', 'e,g', 'a,d,f,g', 'e'],
'Match':['True','True','True','False','False','True']
})
```

Kindly help me with this

Comment: what do you have in your actual dataframe, numbers, letters or mixed?

Comment: What if there are duplicated item, like `a,a` with `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
df['Match']=df['X'].apply(set)==df['Y'].apply(set)
```

Basically, what I'm doing here is to convert each data point from each column into a set, and then comparing them.

It should work independently of the kind of thata (numbers or strings for example).

Notice, however, it wont differenciate if there're replicates. For example, if you have 'a,c,c,b' vs 'a,c,b', that would yield True.

Answer (score 1):

You can try split the column to list then sort and compare.

```py
df['Match2'] = df['X'].str.split(',').apply(sorted) == df['Y'].str.split(',').apply(sorted)
```

Or you can convert list to set and compare depending on if you want duplicated

```py
df['Match2'] = df['X'].str.split(',').apply(set) == df['Y'].str.split(',').apply(set)
```

```
print(df)

         X        Y  Match  Match2
0        a        a   True    True
1    a,b,c    a,c,b   True    True
2      a,d      d,a   True    True
3      e,f      e,g  False   False
4  a,c,d,f  a,d,f,g  False   False
5        e        e   True    True
```

To avoid repeating, you can do

```py
df['Match'] = df[['X', 'Y']].apply(lambda col: col.str.split(',').apply(sorted)).eval('X == Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this, one way would be to explode your arrays, sort them and match for equality.

```
import numpy as np

df1 = df.stack()\
        .str.split(',')\
            .explode()\
            .sort_values()\
            .groupby(level=[0,1])\
            .agg(list).unstack(1)


df['match'] = np.where(df1['X'].eq(df1['Y']),True,False)

         X        Y  match
0        a        a   True
1    a,b,c    a,c,b   True
2      a,d      d,a   True
3      e,f      e,g  False
4  a,c,d,f  a,d,f,g  False
5        e        e   True
```